# mysql[fulltext search]- show search term used to get that particular result

Tags: mysql

For a `like` search i would do-

```
select name,"term1" as searchterm from articles where name like "%term1%"
union
select name,"term2" as searchterm from articles where name like "%term2%"`
```

How do i get the term used get that particular result in an `OR` search with fulltext search?
Is there a way to do it like this -

```
SELECT name,searchterm FROM articles WHERE MATCH (name)
 AGAINST ('term1 term2' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (it was tested on local and its working):

```
SELECT
    tmp1.msg,
    tmp2.tag_name
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(name USING utf8) as msg 
    FROM 
        `articles` 
    WHERE 
        MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('term1 term2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) as tmp1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CONVERT('term1' USING utf8) as tag_name
    UNION
    SELECT CONVERT('term2' USING utf8) as tag_name      
) as tmp2
    ON tmp1.msg LIKE CONCAT('%',tmp2.tag_name,'%')
```